# Terminate thread, process, function in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, kill, terminate

I'm quite new at python and for a while I try to fight specific problem. I have function to listen and print radio frames.To do that I'm using NRF24 Lib and whole function is so easy. The point is that I run this function and from time to time I need to terminate it and again run. So in code it looks like

```
def recv():
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0])
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
    radio.startListening()
    radio.stopListening()
    radio.printDetails()
    radio.startListening()
    while True:
        pipe = [0]
        while not radio.available(pipe):
            time.sleep(10000/1000000.0)
        recv_buffer = []
        radio.read(recv_buffer)           
        print(recv_buffer)
```

I run this function from a server side and now I want to stop it and run again? There is it posible ? why I just cant recv.kill()? I read about threading, multiprocessing but all this didn't give me proper result.

How I run it:

```
    from multiprocessing import Process
      def request_handler(api: str, arg: dict) -> dict:
          process_radio = Process(target=recv())

      if api == 'start_radio':
           process_radio.start()
           ...

      elif api == 'stop_radio':
           process_radio.terminate():
           ...
...
```

Comment: How do you run this function?  Are you using threading explicitly?  Killing a *process* is operating system dependant, but you might be able to setup some signal handling to interrupt the function in some other way, its difficult to advise without knowing how it is run.

Comment: @cdarke It's quite more complicated. I have many functions and this fucntions run at the same time. I have server and client app using procbridge and like I said I need to run this function for listening radio frames and from time to time I need to totally terminate it. So I have server side and it all the time wait for some commands from client side. Client side gives command to run recv function and then I need to use command to terminate it

Comment: @cdarke I need to addmint that I can not just radio.stopListening because I use other functions to listen other frames and just need to terminate whole function to avoid some troubles

Comment: Are you using threading or are these functions running in different processes?  Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @cdarke I tried using threading and processing something like :
`thread_radio = Thread(target=recv(), args=()) thread_radio.start` to start and `thread_radio._stop()` and this to stop it but it didnt work. Similar way with Process `process_radio = Process(target=recv()) process_radio.start` and then to kill it `process_radio.terminate`. And I'm using Raspbian

Comment: How are you running them now?  Are you using threading or are you running the functions in separate processes?

Comment: For now I have variable  process_radio = Process(target=recv()) and If I want to start it I use process_radio.start and when I want kill it I use process_radio.terminate

Comment: @BengBeng: Update ([edit]) your question post with code you give in the comments. On Stack Overflow comments are secondary things, and all information about the problem should be in the question post itself.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Process`, it presumably comes from the library that you are using - I suggest you add a tag for that library.  I can't look it up because you don't give the name of the module.  But if you can kill it using `process_radio.terminate` then I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: I updated a code

Comment: Where does `Process` come from?

Comment: @cdarke, look now

Comment: So why can't you use `terminate`?

Comment: @cdarke it didn't work, when I run in other function radio.startListening `recv()` function start listening as well

Comment: It sounds like a logic error in your code structure.  Do you have a `if __name__ == '__main__':` trap in your code (see the `multiprocessing` doc.)?

Comment: @cdarke in main I just have start server and it waits for this 'api' like start_radio

Comment: Are you sure that this is not being executed every time you call `Process()`?  Check and display the PID, I suspect that this gets re-run, so the `recv()` is being terminated, but a new one is being created when you call `Process()` again, even though the `target` is different.  That's speculation though, using `ps -fu $USER` from the command-line (bash) might shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop a Python thread "from the outside." If the thread goes into a wait state (e.g. not running because it's waiting for `radio.recv()` to complete) there's nothing you can do.

Inside a single process the threads are autonomous, and the best you can do it so set a flag for the thread to action (by terminating) when it examines it.

As you have already discovered, it appears, you *can* terminate a subprocess, but you then have the issue of how the processes communicate with each other.

Your code and the test with it don't really give enough information (there appear to be several NRF24 implementations in Python) to debug the issues you report.